# Why does the <link> ‘title’ attribute cause browsers to ignore my styles?

Tags: html, css

The following html document (together with the CSS) fails to render the styles in `b.css`.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" type="text/css" title="A" href="a.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" type="text/css" title="B" href="b.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="A">A</div>
        <div id="B">B</div>
    </body>
</html>

/* a.css */
div#A   { color: blue;  }
/* b.css */
div#B   { color: red;   }
```

Making the titles the same (e.g. both `<link ... title="A">` fixes it, but I don't see the reason, why it should. What is the title doing, here, that makes this wrong?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

[The HTML spec states that there are three kinds of stylesheets](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/present/styles.html#h-14.3.2): persistent, preferred, and alternate.

- A stylesheet is "persistent" if it is linked with `rel="stylesheet"` and has no `title` attribute. All persistent stylesheets are used when rendering.
- A stylesheet is "preferred" if it is linked with `rel="stylesheet"` and has a `title` attribute; preferred stylesheets with the same `title` are grouped together, but there should not be more than one group. It seems browsers will choose just one preferred stylesheet to render since there should be only one.
- Finally, a stylesheet is "alternate" if it is linked with `rel="alternate stylesheet"` and has a `title`.  These stylesheets are supposed to allow the user to choose stylesheets, they are grouped together by `title` and show up in the browser's stylesheet selector if it has one (View >> Page Style in Firefox).  Each group (by title) is mutually exclusive.

By putting `title` attributes on your stylesheets, you're unwittingly making them into preferred stylesheets rather than the expected persistent stylesheet.  This is also why they work when they all have the same title.

Answer (score 1):

Following up on Neil Williams' answer:

> Authors may specify a number of **mutually exclusive** style sheets called alternate style sheets.... User agents should allow users to select from alternate style sheets.

(emphasis added)

Also:

> To make a style sheet preferred, set the rel attribute to "stylesheet" and name the style sheet with the title attribute.

This is from http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/present/styles.html#h-14.3.1

Answer (score -1):

Read this: http://blogs.telerik.com/dimodimov/posts/08-05-15/title_attributes_in_css_link_tags_prevent_styles_from_being_applied.aspx

> I have been aware for some time now
> that title attributes in CSS 
> tags trigger problems and prevent some
> CSS styles from being applied on the
> web page. Today I invested a couple of
> hours in finding out what actually
> happens and this is what we've got.
>
> If you have several  tags in the
> page  and one of them has a
> title attribute, then the  tags
> coming after it must either have a
> title attribute with the same value or
> no title attribute at all, otherwise
> the styles in the latter CSS files the
> will not be applied on the page.
>
> The issue can be easily reproduced in
> various versions of Firefox, Opera and
> Safari. The only browser, which does
> not exhibit the unexpected behavior is
> Internet Explorer.

Comment: This is not particularly correct, rather is correct in the same way that a broken clock is right twice a day. It is not the correct explanation for what is happening here.