# Only the first CSS stylesheet loads

Tags: html, css, xhtml

I gotta admit that's a first-timer bug for me. I've never seen that...

I have this code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="<?php echo $lang; ?>" >
<head>
    <title><?php echo PAGE_TITLE; ?></title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="all" type="text/css" title="General" href="./res/css/general.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="all" type="text/css" title="Popup" href="./res/css/popup.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="all" type="text/css" title="test" href="./res/css/test.css" />

</head>
<body>
    Hello !
    ...
    absolutely no problem here !!!
    ...
</body>
<html>
```

I believe nothing's wrong with it, only there must be. When I test the page, all the HTML shows up, but without the appropriate style. In fact, only the first stylesheet has any effet on the style.
I tried putting the first file code (working) in one of the other files, and it doesn't work anymore.

I tried googling, but couldn't find anything (maybe I didn't search well too)... I also tried different paths, but it works on the first one, why not the others. I tried renaming the files. I also created the 3rd one especially for that, hoping I just had the name wrong.

It has obsessed me for the last hour... So, I believe I could use some help...

Thanks in advance !
Regards from France ;)

Comment: In what browser does this happen? What does Firebug's "net" tab say - do the files get loaded? Also, are you sure that `./res...` is the path you want (it's relative to the current document)?

Comment: Probably going to be migrated to Doctype.com, but that website sucks. The people there are horrible. I wish we could ask these questions on THIS website.

Comment: @Sergio you *can* ask these questions on this web site. :) I've rarely seen css/html questions getting closed as off topic on SO.

Comment: @Pekka : I tried FF, Chrome & Safari. The file appears on the source code, and on the res and css tabs on firebug, and loaded (I can access the CSS code)

Comment: @Pekka : and yeah the path is correct (works on the first one)

Comment: @Squ Strange. Any possibility to set up a live link?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you [link to an external style sheet](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/present/styles.html#style-external) and set a title for it, you specify it as a preferred style sheet:

> To make a style sheet preferred, set the rel attribute to "stylesheet" and name the style sheet with the title attribute.

But only the first preferred style sheet is used:

> If two or more `LINK` elements specify a preferred style sheet, the first one takes precedence.

Comment: Oh my god. You just saved my live. After about 5 hours of searching in the internet. +1

Answer (score 1):

OK, I got it !!!
I don't know why, but `title` attributes were the thing that blowed the entire thing over. Don't ask me why I have absolutely no idea...

Comment: Ahh, of course! Didn't think of that. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1959959/why-does-the-link-title-attribute-cause-browsers-to-ignore-my-styles for an explanation why.