# Bootstrap / Bootswatch stylesheet changer that actually works

Tags: javascript, performance, twitter-bootstrap, stylesheet, bootswatch

I'm trying to build dynamic CSS stylesheet changer, as simple as possible, for Bootstrap / Bootswatch. I've seen many sources, but I found that most examples relies on additional `title` attribute of `link` tag. And thus, doesn't work in all browsers or works wrong (mainly because of [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1959959/why-does-the-link-title-attribute-cause-browsers-to-ignore-my-styles)).

I also noticed, that using `title` or `rel="alternate stylesheet"` isn't perfect idea, as though styles listed this way are "ignored" (not rendered) upon initial page load, they are somehow parsed, making browser unbelievable slow. I've added two or three Bootswatch styles next to default Bootstrap stylesheet and I nearly killed my Chrome, though page was rendered only with default styling.

Can someone show an example of dynamic stylesheet changer or proper use-case of `title` and `rel="alternate stylesheet"` attribute, that would not consume all my computer resources?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Turned out](http://www.cssnewbie.com/simple-jquery-stylesheet-switcher/#.UdusmTv0F0o) to be as simple as declaring "*default*" stylesheet using `title` attribute:

```
<link href="assets/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" title="main">
```

Then adding some links in form of list (can be used for building Bootstrap's dropdown):

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">

  <li><a href="#" class="change-style-menu-item" rel="assets/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css"><i class="icon-fixed-width icon-pencil"></i> bootstrap.min.css (Default)</a></li>

  <li><a href="#" class="change-style-menu-item" rel="assets/bootstrap/bootstrap.cyborg.min.css"><i class="icon-fixed-width icon-pencil"></i> bootstrap.cyborg.min.css (Cyborg)</a></li>

</ul>
```

with `rel` attribute poining with full path to additional stylesheet.

And then adding a very simple jQuery function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
/*<![CDATA[*/
    jQuery(function($)
    {
        $('body').on('click', '.change-style-menu-item', function()
        {
            $('link[title="main"]').attr('href', $(this).attr('rel'));
        });
    });
/*]]>*/
</script>
```

Works like a charm.

If you have *only one* stylesheet in entire page, you can omit adding `title` attribute to `link` tag and "catch" it using simple `$('link')` selector instead of `$('link[title="main"]')`. Since I had other stylesheets included (`bootstrap-responsive.min.css`), referencing "changeable" stylesheet with `title` attribute was obligatory.

Answer (score -3):

I would take a look at the twitter bootstrap project, they in my humble opinion have extremely cleanly written code and also should be every browser compliant.

http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link href="assets/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

and you should take a look at this page.

http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#responsive

Comment: The OP is using bootstrap already. Why are you telling them something they already know?